# Cannot vote to delete after reaching 10k today

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

I reached the 10k today (Hurraaa!) and trying now to use the Mod-tools. Everything seems to work fine, except I don't see a possibility to cast delete votes.

e.g. using the tools I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803102/my-mobile-number-is-inorrect-and-how-can-i-change-it) and would like to add my delete vote, but how?

To my understanding it should be around and in the style of the reopen and flag link, like I can see it on my own posts.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: If you JUST got 10k rep, maybe it takes some time before you actually get all the privelages... just like badges. You earn the badge, but it won't show it or tell you until later..

Comment: LOL at that question.  Wow.

Comment: I reached it 2 or 3 hours ago and all other privileges coming with it worked right after reaching it.

Comment: Congrats!  10.1K and climbing!

Comment: @jadarnel27 I don't know, I think I could have edited it back into shape :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [10K privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools):

> You must wait for a question to be closed for **2** days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for [trusted users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user).

The question was posted only three hours ago, so it can't possibly have been closed for the prerequisite two days yet.

Comment: OK, thanks, so its my fault. I am so overwhelmed by the create new possibilities that I didn't read close enough.